# sql confusion LEFT JOIN = BETWEEN

Tags: php, sql

Is it possible to check values using BETWEEN and '=' in left join? Something like this ...

```
 LEFT JOIN abc 
        ON abc.date = BETWEEN $a AND $db
```

This query isnt working :( .any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
 LEFT JOIN abc 
    ON abc.date BETWEEN $a AND $b
```

Ie. You need to remove that `=`.

Comment: @cute "It's not working" is almost never a phrase to use when trying to describe your problem. Please be more specific. Have you already looked up BETWEEN in mysql's excellent reference documentation?

Comment: @cute: What happens when you try it? Is there an error, or does it return the wrong results? We need more details.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equality sign before the between. I dont know much about PHP, but SQL usually expects dates in an appropriate format, usually YYYY-MM-DD, and some DBMS do accept other formats as well, such as MM/DD/YYYY, being able to recognize them.

And note that there is no actual joining between the a and abc tables, so, for every register in 'a', SQL will include all the columns in 'abc', but with no record. You have to actually join the tables, using something as such:

```
select    *
from      a
left join abc
on        a.ID = abc.ID
and       abc.date between '$a' and '$db'
```

You can stull filter by any criteria, but you must join the tables. The difference is, when there is no match between the left table (a) and the right table (abc), the right data will be shown as NULLs in the result.

Hope it helps and be useful.